# Issues with getting video duration from dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I have an application where i use dropbox-api V1 to get the video duration from files user shares from dropbox. Recently it broken, but I didn't change my codes.
I decided to migrate to dropbox-api V2, but it didn't solve my problem.

I'm now using dropbox-sdk-js as follows:

```
dropbox.sharingGetSharedLinkMetadata({
   url: url
}).then((
   dropbox.filesGetMetadata({
      path: file.id,
      include_media_info: true
   }).then((metadata) => {
      console.log(metadata)
   })
})
```

But metadata.media_info.metadata object doesn't include the video duration.

I wonder if this is a bug in dropbox-api??

Note: for very rear cases it returns the duration, but i need to get it for all cases.

**Update**

It was an issue in dropbox and seems it is fixed end of December, 2016.
The issue was only with files newly uploaded to dropbox.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/duration-missing-from-video-info/m-p/170084#M6346 ]

Comment: This issue is fixed now, but no any comment on dropboxforum, so don't know if we have guaranty this issue will not happen again

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and apologies for the lack of updates. Yes, this was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! Is there regression testing add/improved of such cases so we can make sure issue doesn't happen again

Comment: Yes, we have improved our testing around this to try to avoid any such issues again in the future. Note that this value is marked optional, however, so it is not guaranteed to be available for every video file. (From [the documentation for VideoMetadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata): "duration UInt64? The duration of the video in milliseconds. This field is optional.")

Comment: Thanks Greg for info!